# How to add custom type conversion error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to display custom type conversion error message?

I have `Nullable<DateTime>` property in model.
If I pass some nonsense value like `1` as `DateTime` I get an error message:

`The field {propertyName} must be a date.`

How can I override this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this message was displayed is because of html attribute:

`data-val-date="The field {propertyName} must be a date."`

I fixed this issue by inserting this attribute by hand

```
var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>())
    {
        { "data-val-date", "CUSTOM_MESSAGE_HERE" }
    };
```

Comment: Then it is not FluentValidation that throw the error message. Please, remove the FluentValidation tag from the Question

Answer (score 0):

You can specified the error message in the rules:

```
public class ModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyModel>
{
    public ModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.StartDate)
            .WithMessage("Invalid start date");
    }
}
```

Comment: Type converesion validation is ran before model validation